# Asynchronous I/O BEAM API for External Data Acces

Tags: apache-beam

I am curious to know whether the [Asynchronous I/O Flink API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/) for External Data Access is also available for Beam. I could not find anything specifically. I know that Beam uses Flink as execution framework so async I/O may be possible for Beam as well but I am not sure the API was defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything related in Beam's Flink runner codebase and I believe that it's not so easy to do (not sure that it's even possible) since all Beam IOs are implemented in the unified way that they have to be run on different runners. So, any of specific data processing things or optimisations have to be used directly by that runner, that is used to run a Beam pipeline on this platform (Flink in your case), during pipeline translation stage and still stay inside the limits of Beam model.